# Source of story about the Vilna Gaon and immigration policy

Tags: vilna-gaon, story-identification, sodom-ammorah, hasidic-story

Internet Judaism gadfly [Dov Bear](http://haemtza.blogspot.com/2007/04/who-is-dov-bear.html) related the following story about the [Vilna Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/DovBear/posts/2283668445043685), saying he'd heard it somewhere, and asked if anyone knows a source for it.

> The great Gaon of Vilna sat with voice but no vote on the Council of the Jews of Vilna. His task was to comment from a Torah perspective on new legislation proposed before the Council. When there was no such new legislation, he did not take part in the meeting.
>
> One day a member of the Council put forward a proposal for greatly reducing the influx of Jews from poorer regions into Vilna, where they hoped for a better life. The Gaon rose to leave the meeting. "But Rabbi," said a Councilmember, "we need your comment on this proposed new legislation!"
>
> "What new legislation?" said the Gaon. "This was already the law of Sodom, long ago!" And he left.
>
> The proposal was dropped.

Is this story documented anywhere?

Comment: The following source puts the setting of the story in Berditchev, and the rabbi being Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev. https://books.google.co.il/books?id=8pxv3NpOLdEC&pg=PA318&lpg=PA318&dq=%22rabbi%22+ancient+enactment+%22sodom%22&source=bl&ots=UbfIgxHmJc&sig=ACfU3U3MfbYzxQ9rr7LY0FXw2Ho7zeRuVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi85qy1gbfjAhVR2qQKHVKfA6sQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22rabbi%22%20ancient%20enactment%20%22sodom%22&f=false

Comment: @IsraelReader Post an answer!

Comment: I hardly consider it to be an answer. By the same token, it can be added to the question. The OP asked for a documented source, and this hardly fills this requirement. To add to the confusion, I've also remember reading a similar story regarding R' Yonason Eibeschitz or the Noda BeYehuda.

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: @DonielF I can't see why not. It's about a prominent rabbinic authority applying Torah precedent.

Comment: Is “gadfly” a derogatory description? If so, we should probably remove or replace it?

Comment: @Menachem I didn't mean it derogatorily, and FWIW, DB saw this post, thanked me for it (in the FB thread linked above), and didn't object to that adjective. I don't object to replacing it, though. "Provocateur"?

Comment: I heard this story about the Vilna Gaon with the additional wrinkle that the Gaon said it was already considered by the Vaad of Arba Aratzot.  The lay leaders looked in history of Mainz, Speyer & Worms and found nothing.  Gaon explained he meant Sodom, Gamorrah, Admah, Zeboiim and Bela.  On looking it up, this is complicated by the Biblical example having 5 places and the Ashkenaz example having 3.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds very similar to the story with R' Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev, but that story is about Tzedakah, not immigration. (Which makes sense, because I don't think there was a restriction against immigrating to Sedom. After all, Lot did it, and was even appointed judge there).

---

Here's the story ([Sippurei Chassidim link](https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=NnyuhrzRDCMC&lpg=PA70&ots=e6oMCZnrkr&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q&f=false). I copied it from [here](http://www.israel613.com/books/TZEDDAKA-E.pdf))

> When Reb Levi Yitzchak accepted the appointment of Rav of Berditchev, he
>   stipulated that the local lay leaders were not to burden him with attendance
>   at communal meetings, unless some new custom was to be ordained.
>
> In due course they called a meeting which was to introduce a new
>   regulation: That paupers would be forbidden henceforth to knock on the
>   doors of householders; instead, they would be given a monthly grant from
>   the community chest. In anticipation of the new statute, they invited Reb
>   Levi Yitzchak and, at the meeting, proceeded to explain their proposition.
>
> Reb Levi Yitzchak protested: "My brothers! Did we not agree that I was not
>   to be bothered with discussions over old regulations?"
>
> "Begging your pardon, rabbi, this is a new piece of legislation!'
>
> Reb Levi Yitzchak was not convinced: "There is nothing novel in your
>   proposal. In fact it has an ancient history, dating all the way back to Sodom
>   and Amora. They too had a statute forbidding people to give alms to the
>   needy... "
>
> The proposal was removed from the agenda there and then.

Comment: The immigration aspect most likely comes from the fact that the people from Sodom were known to not welcome new comers to the city, as is mentioned by Rashi regarding Lot standing near the entrance to the city.

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein actually begins the issue of Jewish Federations on this note, "let's assume it's a centralized tzedaka fund to which the poor can go; okay that's fine, but that doesn't preclude them from also approaching individuals." (He then acknowledges that today's federations often fund things we're not crazy about, but concludes as a matter of practicality that we have to support Federations regardless.)